# LINQ dynamic expression with string join

Tags: c#, sql, linq, expression

I have this code from my current project

```
public Expression<Func<MyObject, object>> CreateSelectExp(a, b)
{
    return x => new
    {
        x.Id,
        x.Status,
        x.DateCreated,
        x.Theme,
        Message = MergeMessage(db, x.Id)
    };
}

private IQueryable<string> MergeMessage(ConnectTo db, Guid id)
{
     return db.MsgHistory
         .Where(s => s.FK_MsgHistory_MsgID.Id == id)
         .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Message))
         .Select(s => String.Join(Environment.NewLine, s.Message));
}
```

What I get is IQueryable which in the end (on the client-side) looks like this `["Text One","Text Two", "Text Three"]` but what I need is one string like this `Text One, Text Two, Text Three`. As I have an SQL expression string in `CreateSelectExp()`, I can't get any List() or Array() out in there. 
I've read about Aggregate but all my tryings gave no result. So the question is how to get one single merged string with linq expression?

Comment: What's the point of `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, s.Message)`? I'm curious, when does it return anything other than `s.Message`?

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Join(
    "\n",
    db.MsgHistory
    .Where(s => s.FK_MsgHistory_MsgID.Id == id)
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Message))
    .Select(s => s.Message))
```

Should do the trick

EDIT:
you can use different separator like ", " if you want everything in one line.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a collection of type `IQueryable<string>`. You need to return a single string.

```
private string MergeMessage(ConnectTo db, Guid id)
{
    return string.Join(", ",
        db.MsgHistory
        .Where(s => s.FK_MsgHistory_MsgID.Id == id)
        .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Message))
        .Select(s => s.Message))
}
```

Comment: Piotr's answer is right, but does not explain why he is getting `["Text One","Text Two", "Text Three"]` and what is the correct method signature

Comment: *What I get is IQueryable* - seems like OP already knows he is getting an `IQueryable`. *how to get one single merged string* - he also seems to know that he wants a single `string` ;) Though, clarifying the question itself isn't bad practice :)